# passing empty query string to php

Tags: php

i have question for query string

i have page wehere i pass query string like that

```
      abc.php?id=12
```

some time query sting "id" is not passed like

```
      abc.php
```

and some time value of id is empty

```
     abc.php?id=
```

and in the above 2 possibilities pages gives error.

how to fix this ?

Comment: Always pass the id? I don't really get what is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check it correctly using `isset()` and `empty()` you should be able to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Check if $_GET['id'] is set (using isset() ) before attempting to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Applying checks using the isset() language construct will supress errors and allow you to access array keys that may not exist. Here is a small function for transparent existance of a value.

```
$myID = getInput('id'); // Returns 'null' if ID doesn't exist but throws no PHP errors
$myID = getInput('id', 50); // Returns 50 if your ID doesn't exist
```

With this you can perform validation checks to make sure you have an ID

```
if( ($myID = getInput('id', 0)) < 1) {
     die('Invalid ID Value');
}
die("My ID is: $myID");


function getInput($key, $default = null) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) && $_GET[$key] != null ? $_GET[$key] : $default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate the incoming data before using it. In this case use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to test if the variable exists and has a value other than *null* and use [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) to check if the value consists only of digit characters.

Answer (score -1):

check the below condition

```
if($_GET['id'] == '') {

 // Your Condition Here

} else if($_GET['id'] != '') {

 // Your Condition Here

} else if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

 // Your Condition Here

}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: can any body explain me why this is low commented

Comment: I'd suspect it's because that code triggers an E_NOTICE error every time the id parameter is not passed to the script and you should always work with full error_reporting and not clutter it with avoidable error messages. (Just a guess, didn't vote)

Comment: I think because this will still throw E_NOTICE error which he asks specifically how to avoid in the question.